# How can I remove all instances of minimum values from array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to prepare for [USACO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_of_America_Computing_Olympiad) Bronze by doing some practice problems on [Codeforces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeforces), and I've been struggling on this one for a good two weeks.

[Here's](https://codeforces.com/gym/103886/problem/A) the prompt.

At first, I was iterating through the array, removing the minimum element, storing the length in a variable, and repeating until there weren't any values left.

However, that was very inefficient and was not working well, so I decided to instead count the number of instances of each element, subtract those from.

The value I expected was 8. However, the value I received was one, leading me to think the variable value keeps getting reset and it only print out the number of times the last/greatest instance occurs.

How do I modify my code so that I'm able to successfully remove the number of instances of the minimum element from the array length, store the new length in a variable and repeat this without any of my values getting reset in the process?

Please excuse me if this is a really dumb question since I'm just starting USACO, and I'm not used to competitive programming yet.

```java
public class sort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        // System.out.println("PLEASE INSERT AN ELEMENT");
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int memory[];
        memory = new int[x];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            memory[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        Arrays.sort(memory);
        int k = memory.length;
        int mem2[] = new int[x];
        int min = memory[0];
        int array[];
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            countFreq(memory, k);
            array = removeElements(memory, min);
            k = k + array.length;
            System.out.println(k);
        }
        System.out.println(k);
        sc.close();
    }

    public static void countFreq(int arr[], int n) {
        boolean visited[] = new boolean[n];

        Arrays.fill(visited, false);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (visited[i] == true)
                continue;
            int count = 1;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                    visited[j] = true;
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static int[] removeElements(int[] arr, int key) {
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            if (arr[i] != key)
                arr[index++] = arr[i];
        return Arrays.copyOf(arr, index);
    }

    public static int[] addX(int n, int arr[], int x) {
        int j;
        int newarr[] = new int[n + 1];
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            newarr[j] = arr[j];

        newarr[n] = x;

        return newarr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly -- your IDE will do this for you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm aware I have a problem with readable code. I'll keep this in mind for the future!

Comment: And your question doesn't explain what your program needs to do -- what is `k`?

Comment: I provided the prompt for that reason but basically, I have to find the length of the array after removing the minimum values, repeat till the array is empty and add up said lengths to find k. Do you need more clarification or is that good?

Comment: Way off-topic: Jess and Jerry evaluated only the time needed to scan the shrinking array. They didn't account for the time needed to find and move the targeted pandas at each pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach used in the code **does not follow the problem description correctly**, and the logic for sorting and counting the operations is not correct.

Some problems are:

- The `countFreq()` method is not used correctly. It's meant to count the frequency of elements in an array, but it's **not utilized in the sorting** process.
- The `removeElements()` method is used to remove occurrences of the minimum element from the memory array, but this approach does **not simulate the described *teleportation* process correctly**.
- The implemented loop does **not match the question**.
- You can use `Java Collections` instead of primitive arrays.

I was based on [the prompt](https://codeforces.com/gym/103886/problem/A) you passed, and I did it this way:

`Main` - Just inputs

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    int[] redPandas = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        redPandas[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    scanner.close();

    int seconds = sortingOperationSeconds(redPandas);
    System.out.println(seconds);
}
```

`sortingOperationSeconds` - Implementation itself

```java
public static int sortingOperationSeconds(int[] redPandas) {
    Queue<Integer> firstLine = new PriorityQueue<>();
    Queue<Integer> secondLine = new LinkedList<>();

    for (int panda : redPandas) {
        firstLine.offer(panda);
    }

    int seconds = 0;
    while (!firstLine.isEmpty()) {
        int flSize = firstLine.size();
        int flSmallestId = firstLine.peek();
        seconds += flSize;
        for (int i = 0; i < flSize; i++) {
            int currentPanda = firstLine.poll();
            if (currentPanda == flSmallestId) {
                secondLine.offer(currentPanda);
            } else {
                firstLine.offer(currentPanda);
            }
        }
    }

    return seconds;
}
```

Let’s step by step:

1. **Red Panda Queues:**

   ```java
   Queue<Integer> firstLine = new PriorityQueue<>();
   Queue<Integer> secondLine = new LinkedList<>();
   ```

   Two [`Queues`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) are created to represent the two lines of red pandas, the `firstLine` is a [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html), where the smallest ID always stays at the front of the queue and the `secondLine` is a [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), where red pandas are moved after being removed from `firstLine`.
2. **Adding Red Pandas to firstLine:**

   ```java
   for (int panda : redPandas) {
       firstLine.offer(panda);
   }
   ```

   [`Offers`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#offer-E-) all red pandas from the `redPandas` array to the `firstLine` queue.
3. **Sorting Operation:**

   ```java
   int seconds = 0;
   while (!firstLine.isEmpty()) {
       int flSize = firstLine.size();
       int flSmallestId = firstLine.peek();
       seconds += flSize;
       for (int i = 0; i < flSize; i++) {
           int currentPanda = firstLine.poll();
           if (currentPanda == flSmallestId) {
               secondLine.offer(currentPanda);
           } else {
               firstLine.offer(currentPanda);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   While `firstLine` is not empty, the loop runs. It calculates the **number of red pandas** in `firstLine` (`flSize`) and the [*smallest ID*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#peek--) in `firstLine` (`flSmallestId`). Then, it adds `flSize` *seconds* to the `seconds` counter.

   The inner loop **removes red pandas** from `firstLine` one by one. If the ID of the current red panda is **equal to the smallest ID** (`flSmallestId`), that red panda is moved to `secondLine`. Otherwise, it is returned to `firstLine`.

   This process **continues until all red pandas have been moved** to `secondLine`.

Answer (score -1):

The main problem with your current approach is that you are modifying the original array **memory** while trying to count the occurrences and remove elements. This leads to unexpected behavior and incorrect results.

Instead of modifying the original array, you can use a separate data structure to keep track of the occurrences of each element and remove the minimum element without altering the array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Sort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int memory[] = new int[x];

        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            memory[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        int min = Arrays.stream(memory).min().getAsInt();
        int minCount = (int) Arrays.stream(memory).filter(num -> num == min).count();
        int k = x - minCount;

        while (minCount > 0) {
            memory = removeElements(memory, min);
            minCount = (int) Arrays.stream(memory).filter(num -> num == min).count();
            k -= minCount;
        }

        System.out.println(k);
        sc.close();
    }

    public static int[] removeElements(int[] arr, int key) {
        return Arrays.stream(arr).filter(num -> num != key).toArray();
    }
}
```

Here's what we did:

1.Instead of using an additional array **mem2**, we directly use the original array **memory**.

2.We find the minimum element in the array and count its occurrences.

3.We remove the minimum element from the array in a loop until there are no more occurrences of the minimum element. In each iteration, we update the count of **k** and recalculate the count of the minimum element to be removed.

By doing this, you can avoid modifying the original array and calculate the correct value of **k** without resetting any values.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with the code, but I'm still facing issues. Now my value outputted when I put in the first test case is 0. Is it possible that maybe while the array was looping, was equal to the minimum count? Just a thought.

Comment: This answer is most likely ChatGPT